# How can I perform a left join comparing two months columns and getting the one right after the other?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

Here's the thing, I have to tables and I want to join them. However, I want to bring the values based on one equality and another comparison. It's like I want to bring the value when the id from the two tables are the same and the other column from table 1 must be below the same column on table 2. Here's my two tables:

table 1 (sales table):

```
id    produts_sold    month
A1    100             '2020-01-01'
A3    500             '2020-01-01'
A1    100             '2020-02-01'
A2    300             '2020-02-01'
A3    200             '2020-02-01'
A1    400             '2020-04-01'
A2    500             '2020-04-01'
A1    400             '2020-06-01'
A1    500             '2020-08-01'
```

table 2 (Price table - shows when the price was updated)

```
id    price    month
A1    100      '2019-12-01'
A2    200      '2019-12-01'
A3    300      '2019-12-01'
A1    200      '2020-02-01'
A1    400      '2020-03-01'
```

Here's the thing, I want to bring the price update for my table. But I don't have the price for each month, just when it was updated. Basically, my final table would be this:

```
id    produts_sold    month             price
A1    100             '2020-01-01'      100
A3    500             '2020-01-01'      300
A1    100             '2020-02-01'      200
A2    300             '2020-02-01'      200
A3    200             '2020-02-01'      300
A1    400             '2020-04-01'      400
A2    500             '2020-04-01'      200
A1    400             '2020-06-01'      400
A1    500             '2020-08-01'      400
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
select t1.*, t2.price
   from table_1 t1
   left join table_2 t2
        on t1.id=t2.id and t1.month > t2.month
```

However, that doesn't work well. Since February-20 is after December-19, but April-20 is also after December-19, I might get the price of April in March, instead of February price. How can I get this left join right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t1.*, t2.price
from table_1 t1 left join lateral
     (select t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.id = t1.id and t2.month < t1.month
      order by t2.month desc
      limit 1
     ) t2
     on true;
```

Note that often with such comparisons, the comparison would use `<=` rather than `<`.

In this case, you can also use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.price
        from table2 t2
        where t2.id = t1.id and t2.month < t1.month
        order by t2.month desc
        limit 1
       ) as price
from table_1 t1;
```

Comment: Is that really a thing from PostgreSQL? I'm asking it because I'm getting a red color on "lateral" and getting the error message: Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "select"

Comment: @DumbML . . . It has been part of Postgres since version 9.4 (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html) which was a pretty long time ago (December 2014).  I should also note that it is standard SQL as well.